# Why SIMToolkit does not trigger registerred EVENTs for my Applet?

Tags: javacard, sim-card, sim-toolkit

In order to debug a problem, I wrote the following applet. This applet simply registers itself for multiple events and then when an event triggers, it set correponding bits (based on the received event type) in a variable named `receivedEvents`. Finally we can receive the value of this variable using a SELECT APDU command.

```
package f0r.god.sake;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

import sim.toolkit.EnvelopeHandler;
import sim.toolkit.ProactiveHandler;
import sim.toolkit.ToolkitConstants;
import sim.toolkit.ToolkitException;
import sim.toolkit.ToolkitInterface;
import sim.toolkit.ToolkitRegistry;

public class SampleSTKApplet extends Applet implements ToolkitInterface, ToolkitConstants {
  private ToolkitRegistry toolkitRegistry;
  private byte receivedEvents = (byte) 0;

  private byte timerId;
  private static byte[] TIMER_VALUE = new byte[] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01};

  private byte menuItemId;
  static byte[] menuItemText = new byte[] { 'C', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'r', 'e'};
 

  private SampleSTKApplet() {
    toolkitRegistry = ToolkitRegistry.getEntry();

    menuItemId = toolkitRegistry.initMenuEntry(menuItemText, (short)0, (short)menuItemText.length,
        PRO_CMD_SELECT_ITEM, false, (byte)0, (short)0);

    toolkitRegistry.setEvent(EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD);
    toolkitRegistry.requestPollInterval((short)15);
    timerId = toolkitRegistry.allocateTimer();
  }
  

  public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
    SampleSTKApplet applet = new SampleSTKApplet();
    applet.register();
  }
  

  public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
    if (selectingApplet())
      ISOException.throwIt((short)((short)0x9000 | receivedEvents));
  }


  public void processToolkit(byte event) throws ToolkitException {
    EnvelopeHandler envHdlr = EnvelopeHandler.getTheHandler();
    ProactiveHandler proHdlr = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();

    switch(event){
      case EVENT_MENU_SELECTION:
        receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x01); // 0b00000001
        byte selectedItemId = envHdlr.getItemIdentifier();

        if (selectedItemId == menuItemId) {
          proHdlr.init((byte) PRO_CMD_TIMER_MANAGEMENT, (byte) 0, DEV_ID_ME);
          proHdlr.appendTLV((byte) (TAG_TIMER_IDENTIFIER | TAG_SET_CR), timerId);
          proHdlr.appendTLV((byte) (TAG_TIMER_VALUE | TAG_SET_CR), TIMER_VALUE, (short) 0,
                  (short) TIMER_VALUE.length);
          proHdlr.send();
        }
        break;

    case EVENT_TIMER_EXPIRATION:
        receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x02); // 0b00000010
      break;

    case EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD:
        receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x04); // 0b00000100
      break;

    case EVENT_STATUS_COMMAND:
        receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x08); // 0b00001000
      break;

    default:
        receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x10); // 0b00010000
    }
  }
}
```

I compiled it and installed it successfuly on my SIM card.

Then:

1. I put that SIM card inside the SIM slot of a turned-off mobile phone.
2. I turned the phone on.
3. I opened the SIM Toolkit applicaiton and then I clicked on the **Click Here** button.
4. I waited about 2 minutes to give enough time to ME to trigger `EVENT_TIMER_EXPIRATION`, `EVENT_STATUS_COMMAND` and `EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD` events.
5. I turned off the mobile phone and put that SIM Card inside my card reader.

Now as I think that all the events have been triggered, I expect `SW = 0x900F (=0x9000 | 0b00001111)` or `SW = 0x901F (= 0x9000 | 0b00011111)` in response of SELECT APDU command. But that's not what I receive:

```
ebr@him:~/SomePath$ apdu_sender -a 00a4040006112233445566 -d
>>> 00A40400 06 112233445566
<<< 9003
```

As you see above, the Status Word to SELECT APDU command in `0x9003 (= 0x9000 | 0b00000011)` and that means the STK triggered `EVENT_MENU_SELECTION` and `EVENT_TIMER_EXPIRATION` only.

**Why other event did not triggered?**

---

**1st Update 2022-10-13: Simulate ME!**

I just put the SIM in a card reader and simulate the role of ME using `TERMNINAL PROFILE`, `FETCH` and `TERMINAL REPONSE` APDU commands to investigate my SIM reaction:

```
>>> A0100000 08 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF   // Simulated Terminal Profile APDU command
<<< 9129  // Card have 0x29 bytes to send

>>> A0120000 29  // Fetch 0x29 bytes 
<<< D027810301250082028182850C53544B2053657276696365738F0B80436C69636B2048657265180124 9000
/*
    D0 27
    81 03 012500 <--- 0x25 = Set Up Menu
    82 02 8182
    85 0C 53544B205365727669636573
    8F 0B 80436C69636B2048657265
    18 01 24
*/

>>> A0140000 0C 810301030002028281030100 // Simulated Terminal Response = Command Performed Successfully.
<<< 910F // Card have 0x0F more bytes to send


>>> A0120000 0F  // Fetch 0x0F bytes
<<< D00D8103010500820281829902090A 9000
/*
    D0 0D
    81 03 010500 <--- 0x05 = Set Up Event List
    82 02 8182
    99 02 090A <-- Event List: Data Available, Channel Status
*/

>>> A0140000 0C 810301030002028281030100 // Simulated Terminal Response = Command Performed Successfully.
<<< 910F // Card have 0x0F more bytes to send

>>> A0120000 0F  // Fetch 0x0F bytes
<<< D00D8103010300820281828402010F 9000
/*
    D0 0D
    81 03 010300 <--- 0x03 = Poll Interval
    82 02 8182
    84 02 010F <--- Duration: 15 seconds
*/

>>> A0140000 10 8103010300020282810301008402010F // Simulated Terminal Response = Command Performed Successfully.
<<< 9000 // No more proactive commands
```

And try to read the `receivedEvents` again:

```
ebr@him:~/SomePath$ apdu_sender -a 00a4040006112233445566 -d
>>> 00A40400 06 112233445566
<<< 9000 <-- Corrected in update! No event received by the applet!
```

---

**2nd Update 2022-10-14: Type Fixed**

I have changed Status Word bytes of the last command above from **9003** to **9000**. It was a typo. The applet doesn't triggered by any event in the simulated ME test!

Comment: Just wrote a comment to your previous question> Have a look into [3GPP TS 43.019](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=2662) for API documentation. Using `requestPollInterval()` should work but actual time may be changed. Try analyzing APDU commands for `POLL INTERVAL` proactive command. Short polling interval drains battery and should be avoided. Please validate my thoughts...

Comment: And regarding the polling -- [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2249547/sim-card-events-problem) is rather interesting.

Comment: @vlp Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question with simulated ME communication using a card reader. It seems that the USIM doesn't send any proactive command for `EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD` and `EVENT_STATUS_COMMAND`. Am I right?

Comment: That is strange -- as far as I understand the applet should receive `EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD` upon reception of `TERMINAL PROFILE`. To receive the `EVENT_STATUS_COMMAND` you will probably need to simulate the `STATUS` APDU command (e.g. from linked article -- `A0F200000F`). It might be worth trying to move the getters for `ProactiveHandler` and `EnvelopeHandler` to the menu selection case (they might throw, but I am not sure). Nevertheless the `requestPollInterval()` method obviously works.

Comment: @vlp Thank you dear vlp. I added an update. `9003` was a typo in the previous update and I received `9000` in the last APDU command (GET `receivedEvents` APDU command). In fact, In the previous update, I wrongly ran the simulation test on the applet that its `receivedEvents` had already been modified in the phone. When I deleted the applet and reinstalled it and run the test again, then the return value was 9000 in the final command. It means no event is received by the applet at all!

Comment: Have you tried moving the getters for `EnvelopeHandler` and `ProactiveHandler`? Or wrap the complete `processToolkit()` body into `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x80); }`

Comment: @vlp Dude, thank you very much! Please post these life saver hints as an answer to let me award you the bounty. I can add details to your answer then. Not sure which one yet, but it seems that one of the getHandler methods raise the "busy" type ToolkitException. Anyway, what makes them busy?

Comment: Anyway, what makes them busy in the beginning of `processToolkit` method? I haven't sent any proactive command in that moment yet! do I? Can registering for event in the applet constructor make it busy?

Comment: My bet is that it is caused by the `EnvelopeHandler` as there is no current `ENVELOPE` APDU when processing the `TERMINAL RESPONSE` APDU (that generates `EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD`) and/or `STATUS` APDU (that generates `EVENT_STATUS_COMMAND`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Transcript of discussion in comments)

Move the getter for the `EnvelopeHandler` to the `EVENT_MENU_SELECTION` as it might throw for events without the `ENVELOPE` APDU command:

```
public void processToolkit(byte event) throws ToolkitException {
    ProactiveHandler proHdlr = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();

    switch(event){
      case EVENT_MENU_SELECTION: {
            EnvelopeHandler envHdlr = EnvelopeHandler.getTheHandler();
            receivedEvents = (byte)(receivedEvents | 0x01); // 0b00000001
            byte selectedItemId = envHdlr.getItemIdentifier();
    
            if (selectedItemId == menuItemId) {
              proHdlr.init((byte) PRO_CMD_TIMER_MANAGEMENT, (byte) 0, DEV_ID_ME);
              proHdlr.appendTLV((byte) (TAG_TIMER_IDENTIFIER | TAG_SET_CR), timerId);
              proHdlr.appendTLV((byte) (TAG_TIMER_VALUE | TAG_SET_CR), TIMER_VALUE, (short) 0,
                      (short) TIMER_VALUE.length);
              proHdlr.send();
            }
        }
        break;

    ...the rest of the code...
```

Good luck with your project!